# Microsoft.Web.Helpers FileUpload Custom Text

Tags: file-upload, web, helper

i am using `Microsoft.Web.Helpers.FileUpload`

```
    @FileUpload.GetHtml(
        name: "file", 
        initialNumberOfFiles: 1, 
        allowMoreFilesToBeAdded: false, 
        includeFormTag: false, 
        addText: "", 
        uploadText: "Upload Logo"
    )
```

when i run my application it displays a button saying `'Choose File'` and text to the right of the button saying  `'No File Chosen`' then when i choose a file it replaces the `'No File Chosen'` with e.g. `'Example.jpg'`

How do i make it so `'No File Chosen'` is not displayed?

Comment: Got curious and am looking at the disassembly in reflector now. It would be fantastic if the documented the darn thing wouldn't it?